# REST API to get a list of active subscriptions in Google Workspace

Tags: google-workspace, google-license-manager

Looking for an API to get list of all subscriptions in Google workspace (not the detailed info about available licenses count etc). It's the same information which is available on Admin console under Billing-> Subscriptions

[Billing/Subscriptions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WeFLH.png)

Answer (score 1):

### If you're a reseller

You can use [subscriptions.list](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/reseller/reference/rest/v1/subscriptions/list) The list can be all subscriptions, all of a customer's subscriptions, or all of a customer's transferable subscriptions.

### If you're a regular Google Workspace customer

You can use [licenseAssignment.list](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/licensing/reference/rest/v1/licenseAssignments/listForProductAndSku). It doesn't display the list itself, but you can filter the elements within the [items property](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/licensing/reference/rest/v1/LicenseAssignmentList) and loop over productId, skuID and [skuName](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/licensing/reference/rest/v1/licenseAssignments#LicenseAssignment)

Comment: Thanks, Yes, I am aware of license manager API but it only returns assigned licenses but not the newly added subscription which is not assigned yet to any user. Also, in order to use this API one needs to know productId corresponding to subscription but that info is not available (it may be any of these https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/licensing/v1/how-tos/products)